# tensorflow 2.0, variable_scope(), TypeError: __call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'partition_info'

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have convert a CNN model from tf1.x to tf2.0 by using `tf_upgrade_v2`, but when i used this converted model, i got an error:

`File "/home/hsw/virtual_env/tf2.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 2492, in default_variable_creator
    import_scope=import_scope, distribute_strategy=distribute_strategy)
  File "/home/hsw/virtual_env/tf2.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 216, in __call__
    return super(VariableMetaclass, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hsw/virtual_env/tf2.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py", line 422, in __init__
    constraint=constraint)
  File "/home/hsw/virtual_env/tf2.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py", line 545, in _init_from_args
    initial_value() if init_from_fn else initial_value,
  File "/home/hsw/virtual_env/tf2.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 886, in <lambda>
    shape.as_list(), dtype=dtype, partition_info=partition_info)
TypeError: __call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'partition_info'`

it seems like something wrong in `variables.py`, and the converted model such as like this :

```
    with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope('backbone', reuse=tf.compat.v1.AUTO_REUSE):
      net = tf.compat.v1.layers.separable_conv2d(inputs, 16, 3, 1, 'same',
                                     activation=tf.nn.elu,
                                     depthwise_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_normal(),
                                     pointwise_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_normal(),
                                     name='conv1')
      net = tf.compat.v1.layers.max_pooling2d(net, 2, 2, padding='same')
      net = tf.compat.v1.layers.separable_conv2d(net, 32, 3, 1, 'same',
                                     activation=tf.nn.elu,
                                     depthwise_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_normal(),
                                     pointwise_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_normal(),
                                     name='conv2')
```

how should do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, and it's been already filed on github. See the discussion there: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26665#issuecomment-472950222